# Type in one textarea while blocking the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen a couple of examples where I could detect with jquery if someone is typing in a textarea. However, I have not found a proper solution to my problem.

I have two textareas and while I am writing in one, I want to block the other textarea, so the user can't access it. However, if the user decides otherwise and deletes the text I want both textareas to be accessable again for the user.

Is there any hint or lead that might help me solve this problem with jquery?

Comment: How will you know when the user is done typing and ready for the next field? Or is this only one will ever be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by using a combination of `keyup` event and the `attr` method. Here is a simple and *reference* code that accomplish something similar that you are asking.

`HTML`

```
<textarea id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

`jQuery`

```
$(function(){
    $('#text1').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length>0){
            $('#text2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        } else if($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('#text2').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $('#text2').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length>0){
            $('#text1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        } else if($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('#text1').attr('disabled', false);
        }        
    });
});
```

And here is this code in [action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcz83741/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
<textarea id="txtArea1"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtArea2"></textarea>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    //Onkeyup listener
    $(document).on('keyup','#txtArea1,#txtArea2',function()
    {
        //If value is empty then enable both
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $('#txtArea1').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#txtArea2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        //If txtArea1 then disable txtArea2
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'txtArea1')
        {
            $('#txtArea2').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        //If txtArea2 then disable txtArea1
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'txtArea2')
        {
            $('#txtArea1').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you have to wrap this on `onload` or put it above the html part ?

Comment: No that's not necessary. The `$(document).on` part will enable the listener. It works in both cases, either if you put it above or beyond the html.

Comment: Yes, you are right.i just tried it.actually i was thinking about the other way around. regardless, it works.